# disappeared slug in administration site

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

i have wrote this codes in admin.py

```
@admin.register(Post)
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['title','slug','author','publish','status',]
    list_filter = ['status','created','publish','author',]
    search_fields = ['title','body',]
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug':('title',)}
```

but when in administration site write some words as title like "this", "for", "as" and ...
they wont write in slug field and disappeared
what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.prepopulated_fields) for prepopulated_fields says that it removes common English words:

> The generated value is produced by concatenating the values of the
>   source fields, and then by transforming that result into a valid slug
>   (e.g. substituting dashes for spaces; lowercasing ASCII letters; **and
>   removing various English stop words such as ‘a’, ‘an’, ‘as’, and
>   similar)**.